# bootstrap-validator: How to place error message in Popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using "1000hz bootstrap validator" https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator to validate my form.

By default, the error messages is placed in the container 
`<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>` after the input field, I want each error to be placed in Popover,like `stackoverflow`.

what should I do?
Thanks in advance.

this is the example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
            </div>
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <div class="help-block with-errors">Hey look, this one has feedback icons!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="form-inline row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <input type="password" data-toggle="validator" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <div class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
                    Boxers
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
                    Briefs
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
                    Check yourself
                </label>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.10.2/validator.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think the plugin that you are using have no option better to switch here http://formvalidation.io/examples/using-tooltip-to-show-message/